# Calculated Column in Custom List - IF Yes then Show

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list, calculated-column

Example Columns:

-Are You Bringing a Guest? Yes/No

-How many Guests are you Bringing? Choice

I'm trying to make it so when/if a user selects "Yes" on the [Are you Bringing a Guest?] column, it shows the next column to the user being [How many Guests are you Bringing?].  If they select No on the initial question, they should not be seeing the following column, but if they select yes, they will be able to answer the following column.

Is this a possibility in modern SharePoint 0365?  Any assistance will certainly be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried customizing list form using powerapps?

Comment: I have not tried that yet as I have not personally used PowerApps. If it appears that it cannot be done via Calc. Column, I may have to learn that, if it is possible in PowerApps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this question could be over complicating things slightly. Most questions with a `true`/`false` answer need to be asked if they're followed up by a second conditional question.

Is it required to have these two fields? Or are there alternatives? You could consider asking for `Number of people Invited` and default that value to `0` in a number only textbox or a combo box. Then any workflows that revolve around this question can query `numInvited > 0` or `numInvited == 0` instead of `invites == Yes` or `invites == No` respectively. This also solves the issue of having a conditional formatting on your list either with PowerApps for SPO or InfoPath for SP on Prem.

In the example below you'd know that Jo's table does have guests. 15 of them, accoridng to the combo box. Then Mo's table obviously has no guests, because there are 0 invited.

```
|                 |          |     |                 |          |
| Q3. Table Name: | Jo's Tbl |     | Q3. Table Name: | Mo's Tbl |
+-----------------+----------+     +-----------------+----------+
|                 |          |     |                 |          |
| Q4. Num Invited:| 15     v |     | Q4. Num Invited:| 0      v |
+-----------------+----------+     +-----------------+----------+
|                 |          |     |                 |          |
```

Let me know if this is unreasonable for your business case. If it is, you could edit the default edit or submit template with PowerApps/InfoPath to "hide" a field based on another value.

Comment: I'm just now getting into PowerApps, but I think I know what you are saying and am going to give a try right now.  Thank you.